# Dedicated Server for Multiple VMs

Tags: server

I currently utilize a single Amazon Web Services EC2 t2.micro server on Windows Server 2012 R2 for my multiplayer gaming services (providing server listings). Due to many reasons, I need to modify the system to utilize an efficient DBMS as well as a web interface.

Currently the EC2 server runs the main server program (uses a local SQLite database), and I use external web-hosting to provide the website.

My initial draft of the new system has a total of three servers, plus an optional fourth for game-server hosting:

- Server 1 (32GB RAM, 4 CPU Cores, 200GB HDD): Database
- Server 2 (8GB RAM, 2 CPU Cores, 100GB HDD): Main Application
- Server 3 (8GB RAM, 2 CPU Cores, 100GB HDD): Web Control Panel
- Server 4 (8GB RAM, 4 CPU Cores, 200GB HDD): Game-server hosting

Hosting all this on AWS would be... expensive, and as a result I'm looking for a dedicated server where I can host these four servers via HyperV (I have a genuine Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter licence, so I can do this easily).

For a database server I understand that RAM and CPU are the most important, and as the main application runs on the t2.micro server without any issues (it uses hardly anything), it does not need much to run. The same can be said for the web control panel, and the game-server hosting VM will be just one game and a couple of servers.

I'm therefore looking for a dedicated server for rent that has the following:

- The ability to use my own Windows Server licence, rather than paying a fee to use theirs;
- Fully dedicated so HyperV can be used (I'll also be [using Bosun](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun), which absolutely requires virtualization to be supported by the CPU
- Supports my desired configuration *and* be sub-£100 (~$132)
- DDoS protection available
- Support for at least three extra IPs (some have a limit on extra IPs, which is why I mention it)
- Must be located in Europe

I have found three servers that match my specification:

- [The £100 server from Zare](https://zare.com/dedicated-servers), including i7 6700K, 64GB DDR4 RAM, 1TB HDD, and DDoS protection
- [MC-128 from OVH](https://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/details-servers.xml?range=GAME&id=MC-128-LD) (slightly over budget), Xeon E5-160 v2, 128GB DDR3 RAM, 2x 480GB SSD, DDoS Protection (*unsure about supporting BYOL- I asked them and will update when they respond*)
- So you Start - 96G ECC 2xE5606 8c/8t HardRaid 2x2TB Server: I reserved this one (at no cost) and can't find it on their site anymore, but at its price point it looks like it is a VPS and not a true dedicated server.

Which of these three servers should I use, and why?